# in chrome : conditional statement fails on jquery/ajax result

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, conditional-operator

this is my code . it sends a ajax request to a page and alerts the result

```
function num(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'num.php',
        success: function(data) {
            data = parseInt($.trim(data));
            if(data == 1 )
                alert(' its num 1');
            else  
                alert(data)
        }
    })
}
```

num.php

```
<?php echo 1; ?>
```

it works fine in ie and ff but in chrome this conditional statement doesn't work for some reason and i get '1' in the alert window

Comment: use `console.log(data)` and see what is happeing.. Alerts are not used for debuggin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my personal experience your num.php file or one of the included files has a bad encoding and it's adding some invisible characters to the result .
try changing encoding to utf8 without bom and remove included files from num.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alerts.. Use `console.log(data)` because it will actually show you the TYPE and you can log more detials isntead of using annoying alerts.

The console could show you potential type conversion  (even though you are using parseInt) it could be cast to string again.. who knows.. because all these browsers use their own J/Engines... conventions could be slightly off.

eg

- data = '1' (chrome)
- date = 1 (ie/ff)

Also `console.log($(object))` reproduces PHP's `print_r(object)`

Alert does not do that.. jsut say [Object object] - Try and steer away from alerts.

Use the Right Click  - Inspect to access the Console in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

For convert string you can try:

```
data = data/1;
```

For compare use '===':

```
if(data === 1 )
```